# Python - Find values whose coordinates are known in several times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to get several values whose i have the coordinates.
My coordinates are given by "Coord" (shape : (3, 3, 2, 3) : X and Y during 3 times and with 2 because of 2 coordinates) and my values are given by "Values" (shape : (3, 3, 3) for 3 times)

In other words, i would like to concatenate values in time with "slices" for each positions...

I dont know how to undertake that...Here there is a little part of the arrays.

```
import numpy as np

Coord = np.array([[[[ 4.,  6., 10.],
     [  1.,   3.,   7.]],

    [[ 3.,  5.,  9.],
     [  1.,   3.,   7.]],

    [[ 2.,  4.,  8.],
     [  1.,   3.,   7.]]],


   [[[ 4.,  6., 10.],
     [  2.,   4.,   8.]],

    [[ 3.,  5.,  9.],
     [  2.,   4.,   8.]],

    [[ 2.,  4.,  8.],
     [  2.,   4.,   8.]]],


   [[[ 4.,  6., 10.],
     [  3.,   5.,   9.]],

    [[ 3.,  5.,  9.],
     [  3.,   5.,   9.]],

    [[ 2.,  4.,  8.],
     [  3.,   5.,   9.]]]])




Values = np.array([[[-4.24045246,  0.97551048, -5.78904502],
        [-3.24218504,  0.9771782 , -4.79103141],
        [-2.24390519,  0.97882129, -3.79298771]],

       [[-4.24087775,  1.97719843, -5.79065966],
        [-3.24261128,  1.97886271, -4.7926441 ],
        [-2.24433235,  1.98050192, -3.79459845]],

       [[-4.24129055,  2.97886284, -5.79224713],
        [-3.24302502,  2.98052345, -4.79422942],
        [-2.24474697,  2.98215901, -3.79618161]]])
```

---

EDIT LATER

I try in case of a simplified problem (without time first). I have used a "for loop" but
somes errors seems subsist...do you think it s the best way to treat this problem? because my arrays are important... 400x300x100

```
Coord3 = np.array([[[ 2,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  2.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 2.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  2.]],

       [[ 2.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])


Coord3 = Coord3.astype(int)


Values2 = np.array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.]])


b = np.zeros((3,3))    

for i in range(Values2.shape[0]):
    for j in range(Values2.shape[1]):
        b[Coord3[i,j,0], Coord3[i,j,1]] = Values2[i,j]

b
```

Comment: the context is a transit to Eulerian to Lagrangian description! i know all the coordinates to transform my values in Eulerian to Lagrangian in several times!

Comment: why do you need this dot next to each number? What's the point

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand...

Comment: why is there a dot `.` next to each of your coordinate numbers????

Comment: It s the form of my coordinates. I have applied some transformations of them and i have around with np.around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is relatively easy to do with fancy indexing:

```
b = np.zeros((3,3), values2.dtype)
b[coord3[..., 0], coord3[..., 1]] = values2
```

The origial problem is a bit harder to do, but I think this takes care of it:

```
coord = coord.astype(int)

x_size = coord[..., 0, :].max() + 1
y_size = coord[..., 1, :].max() + 1
# x_size, y_size = coord.max(axis=(0, 1, 3)) + 1
nt = coord.shape[3]

b = np.zeros((x_size, y_size, nt), values.dtype)
b[coord[..., 0, :], coord[..., 1, :], np.arange(nt)] = values
```